# Why isn't my canvas element deleting on Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to build an interactive "scratch off-able" part of a page using a canvas element which is supposed to be deleted when a certain percentage of pixels are filled in. It's working fine in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but the canvas doesn't get deleted in Edge on a Windows machine. (Annoyingly, it works fine in Edge on Mac.) Any idea why?

Thank you!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container" id="js-container">
  <canvas class="canvas" id="js-canvas" width="298" height="598"></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#creative {
    cursor: grab !important;
    border:1px solid #000; 
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none; 
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
(function () {

  'use strict';

  var isDrawing, lastPoint;
  var container = document.getElementById('js-container'),
    canvas = document.getElementById('js-canvas'),
    canvasWidth = canvas.width,
    canvasHeight = canvas.height,
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    image = new Image(),
    brush = new Image();


  image.src = 'CanvasImage.png';
  image.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

  };
  brush.src = 'data:image/png;base64,[Encoded Image Here]';

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', handleMouseDown, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', handleMouseMove, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchend', handleMouseUp, false);

  function distanceBetween(point1, point2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point2.x - point1.x, 2) + Math.pow(point2.y - point1.y, 2));
  }

  function angleBetween(point1, point2) {
    return Math.atan2(point2.x - point1.x, point2.y - point1.y);
  }

  function getFilledInPixels(stride) {
    if (!stride || stride < 1) { stride = 1; }

    var pixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight),
      pdata = pixels.data,
      l = pdata.length,
      total = (l / stride),
      count = 0;

    // Iterate over all pixels
    for (var i = count = 0; i < l; i += stride) {
      if (parseInt(pdata[i]) === 0) {
        count++;
      }
    }

    return Math.round((count / total) * 100);
  }

  function getMouse(e, canvas) {
    var offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0, mx, my;

    if (canvas.offsetParent !== undefined) {
      do {
        offsetX += canvas.offsetLeft;
        offsetY += canvas.offsetTop;
      } while ((canvas = canvas.offsetParent));
    }

    mx = (e.pageX || e.touches[0].clientX) - offsetX;
    my = (e.pageY || e.touches[0].clientY) - offsetY;

    return { x: mx, y: my };
  }

  function handlePercentage(filledInPixels) {
    filledInPixels = filledInPixels || 0;
    console.log(filledInPixels + '%');
    if (filledInPixels > 40) {
      canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
    }
  }

  function handleMouseDown(e) {
    isDrawing = true;
    lastPoint = getMouse(e, canvas);
  }

  function handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (!isDrawing) { return; }

    e.preventDefault();

    var currentPoint = getMouse(e, canvas),
      dist = distanceBetween(lastPoint, currentPoint),
      angle = angleBetween(lastPoint, currentPoint),
      x, y;

    for (var i = 0; i < dist; i++) {
      x = lastPoint.x + (Math.sin(angle) * i) - 25;
      y = lastPoint.y + (Math.cos(angle) * i) - 25;
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
      ctx.drawImage(brush, x, y);
    }

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
    handlePercentage(getFilledInPixels(32));
  }

  function handleMouseUp(e) {
    isDrawing = false;
  }

})();
```

I haven't been able to test this directly, due to a lack of Windows machine or a Browserstack subscription.

The expected result is that if you "scratch off" at least 40% of the image, the canvas will be removed from the DOM.

Comment: Hi @ST_Kat, I've tried your code, but I'm successfully deleting the canvas element by scratching off at least 40% of the image. Tested OK on Edge, Chrome and Firefox. All on Windows.

Comment: Thanks @KendrickLi! Were you able to test this on Edge 114? That seems to be the specific browser version that has the issue.

Comment: Yes, exactly on 114. Today, I tested again on 114.0.1823.58 and still it works fine here.